# Set generic parameter on initialization - in a subclass

Tags: java, generics

I'm hmm, new to generics and I'm facing a problem here:

```
public class AnimationManager<STATE>{
    void loadAnimation(STATE state){
        //blahblah
    }
}

public class Unit{
    // AnimationManager<SomeType> animationManager; // I don't want this !!!
    AnimationManager animationManager; // i want it's type to be set in a subclass
}

public class MediumUnit extends Unit{
// nvm
}

public class FirstUnit extends MediumUnit{

    enum FirstUnitStates{
        S1, S2;
    }

    // i want to set it's type here, in subclasses (FirstUnit, SecondUnit etc.)
    public FirstUnit(){

        // this is ok, but It still doesn't have a type (it yells that I can remove the type from below statement)
        animationManager = new AnimationManager<FirstUnitStates>();

        // and now the problem - Unchecked call to loadAnimation(STATE) as a member of raw type.
        animationManager.loadAnimation(S1);
    }
}
```

Is this possible to achieve my goal without type casting or something like that? Making a wildcard, Object type?

I want to make it that each Unit (FirstUnit, SecondUnit) can set it's own type in AnimationManager (with his own states stored in it's Enum).

**Edit**

I edited my question, cause I have one more class between Unit and FirstUnit.
Nicolas Filotto solution is perfect, but It doesn't work for my problem - I would have to pass the parameter from FirstUnit to MediumUnit and from MediumUnit to Unit - and it simply doesn't work.

Comment: why it doesn't work? it is how to do it anyway, this is actually for this exact reason that generics have been created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is this:

```
public class Unit<T> {
    AnimationManager<T> animationManager;
```

...

```
public class FirstUnit extends Unit<FirstUnitStates> {
```

**Response Update:**

This is the same Idea you will need to simply parametrized `MediumUnit` too as next

```
public class Unit<T> {
    AnimationManager<T> animationManager;
```

...

```
public class MediumUnit<T> extends Unit<T> {
```

...

```
public class FirstUnit extends MediumUnit<FirstUnitStates> {
```

Comment: and if I have more inheritance, like
Unit > BigUnit > MediumUnit > SmallUnit and I want this in SmallUnit I need to pass the parameter in each of these, right?